Tkinter .App MacOS Runs Weird, but runs Perfect in Terminal Mode Why?
I have created an Tkinter app with one login page and a dashboard on the other page. When I open the .app I have to click Sign In like 20-60 times in order to get into it. On the other hand, if I Right Click to my .app and Show Package Contents>MacOS>terminal file then it works super fast and perfectly.
I tried to debug the problem, by checking the terminal, but then terminal works fine. The .app is having the issue. I have to press 10+ times to the password field in order to set my mouse to write my password. I checked if my code works properly, and it does. It works perfectly in terminal + vscode/Run Code. I've been searching way too much, but could not find any answer to this issue since it might be a different occasion. I can get in touch via Discord #hageshiku. I am in need of help. One thing I tried to solve is the codesigning and notarizing the app. I learnt how to codesign,but I've sent an email to Apple Support in order to open my Dev Account to Apple Store Connect. Thanks in advance with all my heart. Bear in mind that I am new, but I am way to eager to learn. Please help or atleast give me some advice to find a solution.
